# Polymer element already registered error for paper-button

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I'm new to Polymer, and I'm trying to put a `<paper-button>` on my page. This project is based on the Polymer Starter Kit. When I try to use the `<paper-button>` element, I receive an error in the console that says that the name is already registered. I don't know why it says this. I only use the `paper-button.html` reference one time. The error is:

> ```
> Uncaught NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'registerElement' on 'Document': Registration failed for type 'dom-module'. A type with that name is already registered.
> ```

The following is the code that generates that error

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="/src/bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">  
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">

<dom-module id="my-view1">
  <template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
      :host {
        display: block;

        padding: 10px;
      }

      h1 {
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>

    <div class="card">
      <!-- <div class="circle">1</div> -->
      <h1>Gas vs. Electric Car Calculator</h1>
      <paper-button>$20,000</paper-button>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-view1',
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Here is the link to the GitHub repository with the code as well: https://github.com/Renniesb/paper-test. To test out the code, you can download it and run: `npm install` and `bower install`.

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML [import for `paper-button`](https://github.com/Renniesb/paper-test/blob/af43d45/src/my-view1.html#L12) points to a nonexistent path:

```
<link rel="import" href="../src/bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
```

Your `bower_components` are in the project's root directory, not under `src/`. The import should be:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
```

Also, your [`bower.json`](https://github.com/Renniesb/paper-test/blob/af43d45/bower.json#L7-L19) is missing a dependency on `paper-button`. You can add it with:

```
bower install --save PolymerElements/paper-button
```

As discovered in chat, you're using Chrome 41, which is quite old. I'm not sure what the compatibility is with that version of Chrome. I recommend upgrading.

I confirmed my suggestions work (as in the `<paper-button>` renders properly on the page) in Chrome 55, macOS Sierra.